# bash convert MMM-DD-YYYY variable to YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: bash

I am working in bash.  I have the following variable:

$dt = June-16-2018

I need to convert this value into date format YYYY-MM-DD.  How can I do this?  I have tried:

```
dt_new=$(date –-date="$dt" +%F)
```

...but bash throws error message

> date: illegal time format

Comment: Pretty quotes, `”`, instead of "normal" ones, `"`?

Comment: Sorry.  I copied the pretty quotes in.  They should be normal quotes.  I just updated the post.

Comment: How are you assigning to `dt`? You can't have spaces in the assignment (as you show them), and you can't use `$` on the left-hand side. What's in `$dt` before you call `date`?

Comment: I'm actually assigning dt via a cat with some cleanup work.  I'm running   filedate=$(cat "some_file.csv" | grep "date is:" | awk -F": " '{print $2}' | sed 's/ /-/g' | sed 's/,//g')

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for isn't possible in bash alone as a one-liner. The `date` command's behaviour differs by operating system. If you want to use this command portably, you'll need to account for the different flavours.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function dateconv {
    local newdate
    case "$(uname -s)" in
      *BSD|Darwin)  newdate="$(date -jf '%b-%d-%Y' "$1" '+%F')" ;;
      Linux)        newdate="$(date -d "$1" '+%F')" ;;
      *)            echo "Can't convert this, sorry." >&2; exit 1 ;;
    esac
    echo "$newdate"
}

dateconv "${1:-$(date '+%b-%d-%Y')}"
```

If, however, you want to avoid using external tools at all, you can fake this using slightly more code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function dateconv {
    local m=(z Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec z)
    local year month day

    year="${1##*-}"

    for f in "${!m[@]}"; do
        if [ "${1%%-*}" = "${m[$f]}" ]; then
            month="$f"
            break
        fi
    done
    if [[ $f = "z" ]]; then
        echo "Invalid month: ${1%%-*}" >&2
        exit 1
    fi

    day="${1#*-}"
    day="${day%-*}"

    printf '%04d-%02d-%02d\n' "$year" "$month" "$day"
}

dateconv "${1:-$(date '+%b-%d-%Y')}"
```

This second alternative is a little less clear, a little less flexible, but should work in bash 3 or 4, in Linux or BSD/macOS environments.

Note that the `%b` date format implies an upper case first letter.

Note also that the solutions above assume a format as described in your subject (`MMM-DD-YYYY`) rather than your example (`June-16-2018`). You can undoubtedly adjust this to whichever format is the one you're actually using.

Comment: The line starting `for f ...` looks odd to me. Shouldn't the `!` be a `#`?

Comment: @MarkSetchell - There exist multiple ways to handle this. `${!m[@]}` expands to the set of indices for the array, whereas `#` just provides the count. In this case, where we know there are always only 12 months, we could use `{1..12}` instead, but handling this with the `!` is obviously educational. :-)  (Note also the first element of the `$m` array, to fill the `0` index.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use -v option to do this:

```
date -v $dt '+%Y-%m-%d
```

results in OS X terminal:

```
2018-06-12
```

Comment: How can i see this?. No information about version in man page

Comment: Yes I tried it too. Maybe reason is I am using osx? `date --version
date: illegal option --version`

Comment: Ah. So you have an OS specific version of date. Thought so. Make sure that's clear in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will work in any GNU `date`:

```
$ date -d'June-16-2018' +%Y-%m-%d
2018-06-16
```